# Internet Explorer 11 is Not Submitting HTTPOnly Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, httponly, cookie-httponly

So I'm working with an application that sends back an ID for the browser to use in future XHRs in an httponly cookie.

However, in future requests to the server, this cookie is not being submitted in IE11 on Windows 7. This works in Opera, Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.

[image: Here's the initial request and the cookie supposedly being set.]

- I've made sure that the withCredentials property on the XHR is set to true in accordance with [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials).
- [Tried with Protected Mode both on and off.](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1227)
- Lowered security to the lowest settings in Internet Options.
- Made sure that the server I'm working with does not have an underscore.
- Made sure CORS is working and it looks like it is

Any help on this would be great! I'm totally stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!

Make sure that the Privacy Settings in the Internet Options accepts third party cookies! You can do this by either making sure the Privacy Settings are at a setting lower than medium or manually accepting first- and third-party cookies in the Advanced Settings.